# RTC or AccuRev which is better?

Tags: compare, rtc, accurev

I am looking for some information on comparison between AccuRev and IBM Rational Team Concert.

Between RTC and AccuRev which tool is better for configuration management and why?

Is there any white paper to refer?

Comment: StackOverflow is more for code questions...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective topic. Both products have their pros and cons and at the end of the day, you are going to find people that like and hate one of the products. You would be better off creating a weighted list of requirements for an SCM product, and figuring out which product best satisfies those requirements.